# Meteor / Iron Router: Data from Mongo db collection don't show up in dynamic template page

Tags: mongodb, meteor, routes, publish-subscribe, iron-router

I'm quite new in javascript programing, so I really appreciate any help.

I'm using:

> Meteor (official Windows port) latest version 1.1.0.2 with Iron Router and Autopublish package

What I'm trying to do, shouldn't be hard to do, but something is missing to me.
I just want to load data from Mongo DB collection

```
Movies = new Mongo.Collection('movies');
```

into my **template** in **/client** folder

```
<template name="movie_template">
  <p>Dynamic page test with movieID {{id}}</p>
  <h1>{{name}}</h1>
  <p>{{year}}</p>
</template>
```

my **router.js** file based in **/lib** folder in root of my Meteor project

```
Router.route('/movies/:movieId', function() {
this.render('movie_template', {
    waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe('moviesDetails', this.params.movieId);
    },
    data: function() {
        return Movies.findOne({id: this.params.movieId});
    }
  });
});
```

**publications.js** in **/server** folder

```
Meteor.publish('movieDetails', function(movieID) {
  check(movieID, Number);
  return Movies.find({id: movieID});
});
```

Only one thing what I get is paragraph text without ID. What I'm doing wrong?

Side question:
Do I have to use publish() function while I'm using Autopublish package?
In that case just use Movies.find() instead subscribe()?

**NOTE**: this is my Movie object field keys.

```
{_id, id, name, year}
```

Comment: Try `{{_id}}` - everything else looks fine

Comment: you are doing `movieID` everywhere EXCEPT on `this.params` you have `movieId`. make sure your variables are consistent everywhere :)

Comment: Sir is correct, try this following things, put a console.log just to see whats return the find `console.log(Movies.findOne(this.params.movieId);` and `console.log(Movies.findOne(this.params.movieID);` for better pattern change `:movieID` to `:_id` and use it `this.params._id`

Comment: Thanks for replies, guys, but...
@below9k : It has a purpose. I basicaly copying data from existing db through REST API, so I need that ID in document and use it in next steps. For example in dynamic url I need to use that ID. Is it problem?

Comment: @SirCharlesWatson : I corrected it, but it didn't have effect on app.
Any different ideas??

Comment: try removing `movieId` to `:_id` and use `this.params._id instead` also what below says its change on the html you have `{{id}}` you should use `{{_id}}` `{{id}} dosnt exist and its breaking the rest of the HTML

Comment: Document of Movie has these keys: {_id, id, name, year}
I can rename that "id" on "number", it doeasn't matter, but I don't want use _id instead of "id". That "id" is just number.
Thanks Ethaan for your help.

Comment: so if you don't specify the field `Movies.findOne({id:this.params.MovieID})`, the `findOne` query will take the first argument as the` _id` of the object  check my answer update

Answer (score 0):

@below9k is correct and you should be using `_id` rather than `id`.

**To answer your side question**, with the `autopublish package` it is not necessary to do either [Meteor.publish](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) and [Meteor.subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe)